# Большое количество однотипных объектов

Tags: объекты, json, javascript, оптимизация, ajax

Есть некая страница, на которой отображается список мероприятий(в них - что-то типа участники, название, описание мероприятия). Мероприятия выводятся либо списком, либо таблицей (в контексте вопроса это не важно).

У меня есть три варианта:

1. Либо забить вообще на объекты (с плюшками в виде методов, ну это удобно, черт возьми) и писать все процедурненько на PHP, с парой обработчиков событий на JS.
2. Писать один большой объект в котором хранится вся информация о всех мероприятиях.
3. Больше всего интересующий меня вариант - создать прототип объекта одного мероприятия, и просто конструктить его на каждое подгружаемое мероприятие(ну и соответственно я либо говорю подгружаемым мероприятиям что у них есть прототип, либо просто вызываю из `jQuery $(extend))`?

Спасибо за ответы.

P.S.: мероприятий через какое-то время использования страницы может стать достаточно много, поэтому и возник такой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать простенький парсер таблиц/списков на jQuery. Чтобы парсер автоматом создавал такие объекты.

Comment: Вообще, если таблиц будет много и там много колонок, то можно использовать ExtJS на стороне клиента. Он с таблицами очень хорошо работает, но тогда коммуникацию с сервером придется полностью переводить на ajax.

Comment: ))) вопрос не в том как объекты делать, и делать их руками или автоматом - первоначальный вопрос, в каком случае будет меньше тормозить, что предпочесть - один большой объект или куча маленьких однотипных(в конце концов их может быть в районе 300, в самих объектах будет в принципе немного свойств, никаких перекрытий плюс два метода - 3 в 1 (редактирование, создание, просмотр) и сохранение, возможно еще подгрузка, но я не думаю что это должно быть методом родительского объекта)? В общем - что тормознее, один большой объект, или много-много маленьких?

Comment: (редактирование, создание, просмотр), если добавить сюда еще удаление, то получится CRUD - create, read, update, delete. Это уже RESTом пахнет, батенька. То есть нужно тогда формировать JSON на стороне сервера и отдавать клиенту.

Comment: Это напрашивалось, но на вопрос вы не ответили, хотя и спасибо вам за наводку. Как будут дела обстоять с памятью?

Comment: один большой объект теоритически быстрее, чем куча маленьких. Если взять в расчет, что для каждого такого объекта резервируется место в памяти. Кстати если объекты однотипные, тут само собой напрашивается создание коструктора объектов (класс) и уже на его основе создавать объекты(экземпляры класса).

Comment: не, конструктор будет, с этим все в порядке. спасибо) и если не секрет - как можно узнать сколько памяти это добро занимает в точности? Я имею ввиду - напишу две реализации, с одним большим и кучей маленьких объектов, и нужно посмотреть именно количество памяти под это дело. Это делается какими-то директивами JavaScript'а или чем-то типа профайлера?

Comment: Да. В профайлере хрома есть такая штука https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling . Но мне как-то пока не приходилось пользоваться ею. Так же путем гугления обнаружил вот такую любопытную функцию на js:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11900218 и вот такую http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/finding-the-memory-usage-of-objects/

Comment: @Lucky, это только размер простых объектов считает, а вот скажем, если конструктор создал массив ?

Comment: спасибо, буду смотреть

Answer (score 0):

Что вам мешает сделать это на php не "процедурненько", конечно пишите классы и методы, связываете их. Это легче потом дорабатывать и поддерживать, если кто-то после вас будет что-то делать. Я ни в коем случае не хочу говорить что процедурное программирование плохо, но из опыта, лучше как можно больше продумать сначала, что бы потом бубном не прыгать.

Comment: да нет, я тоже не говорю что процедурное программирование это плохо))) наверное, так прозвучало, извиняюсь, если кого-то обидел, просто... есть две причины по которым я не хочу использовать процедуры - не вижу смысла в них здесь и к тому же (к сожалению, это точно знаю)не умею мыслить процедурно. Насчет серверной части - не умею писать объекты на php, я в основном на js учусь, и к тому же - не будет ли это слишком тяжело для такого рода вещей? Просто первая мысль у меня про объекты php - они должны быть просто глобальнейшие и огромные.

Comment: >>не умею мыслить процедурно
класс=) это хорошо

Я думаю не будет тяжело и громоздко, если грамотно написать класс, ваш сервер будет пархать.

А вообще можно проверить поставив таймер на выполнение и вы сразу для себя решите что вам больше подходит

Comment: опять же по поводу класса - почему он должен быть на серверной стороне, а не на клиентской? это просто вопрос, я просто не знаю, что выбрать

Comment: если вы делаете на php, то на серверной части, js то на ктиентской, я наверное ваш вопрос сейчас не понял

Comment: я имею ввиду что на мне целиком все от и до от создания таблицы до верстки. Разрабатываем по модулям, весь модуль от и до на одном человеке. Вот передо мной выбор - либо сервер занимается только обработкой данных БД(выгрузка и соответственно отгрузка), а на клиенте принимается JSON и полностью парсится здесь, на клиенте ИЛИ же я все делаю криво толком без JS, и делаю объекты на серверной части(причем получится что в большинстве своем эти объекты будут созданы не для работы с данными, а для их отображения на клиенте). По идее, вариант с JS-объектами лучше,поэтому и возник первоначальный вопрос

Comment: в так случаем мне тоже больше по душе предоставить это клиенту

Comment: @abibock_un клиенту то какая разница, ему лишь бы работало.

Comment: Под словом "Клиент" я имел ввиду браузер